# Partition loop understanding

Tags: java, quicksort

Why the loop body of the partition method never throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception?

```
public static int partition( int[] a, low, high ) {

    int k = low, m = low;


    /* loop invariant:
    *     low <= k <= m <= high  and
    *     all elements in a[low..k-1] are RED (i.e., < pivot) and
    *     all elements in a[k..m-1] are BLUE (i.e., >= pivot)
    */
    while (m != high)  {
       if (a[m] >= pivot)     // a[m] is BLUE
          { }
       else  {                // a[m] is RED
          swap(a,k,m);
          k = k+1;
       }
       m = m+1;
    }
    return k;
 }
```

Comment: The code you've given won't even compile, and it certainly *will* throw an exception if you provide inappropriate `low` and `high` values.

Comment: this is part of the code im only interested in the loop body of this method

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list - basically, you haven't given us enough context. I *suspect* you want to give us the context in terms of the relationships between `low` and `high`, and `high` and `a.length` - but without that context, we can't answer the question. (For one thing, because if you provide inappropriate values, it *will* throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.)

Comment: ok thank you i will re post the question

Comment: You don't need to post a new question - just edit this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// m <= high (loop invariant)
while (m != high)  {
    // m < high, hence correct index
    a[m] ...

    m = m + 1;
    // m <= high (loop invariant)
}
```

Mind swap does not change m. Maybe you thought k and m where swapped, but likely a[k] and a[m]. As m is a local int variable, and ints are passed by value.

Even if m and k where swapped: m <= high

The loop invariant k <= m is helt:

```
// k <= m
if (...) {
    swap(a, k, m);
    // m <= old m // if call-by-reference

    k = k + 1;
    // k - 1 <= m if call-by-value
}
m = m + 1;
// k <= m again; if call-by-value
```